# CSS alignment issue for livechat box

Tags: jquery, css

I want to show the livechat box in my every webpage in bottom. I did but the alignment is not working properly. I want to have it be similar to this live chat box example:(https://www.tawk.to/testimonials/). Please help me how do this.

My code is: https://jsfiddle.net/fn77d0de/2/

```js
// JavaScript Document

var username = "";

function send_message(bot_response) {
  var prevState = $("#container").html();

  console.log(prevState.length);

  if (prevState.length > 8) {
    prevState = prevState + "<br>";
  }

  $("#container").html(prevState + "<span class='current_message'>" + "<span class='chatBot'>Chatbot: </span>" + bot_response + "</span>");
  $("#container").scrollTop($("#container").prop("scrollHeight"));
  $(".current_message").hide();
  $(".current_message").delay(500).fadeIn();
  $(".current_message").removeClass("current_message");
  //$("#container").html("<span class='chatBot'>Chatbot: </span>" + message );
}

function get_userName() {
  //send_message("Hello, what is your name?");

  username = "${outParams.userName}";
  send_message("Nice to meet you " + username + ", how may can may I help you.");
}

function ai(newMessage) {

  var id = "1";
  var path = "http://localhost:8080/vfim/chatService.do";

  if (username.length < 1) {
    username = newMessage;
    send_message("Nice to meet you " + username + ", how are you doing?");
  } else if (newMessage.indexOf("how are you") >= 0) {
    send_message("Thanks, I am good!");
  } else if (newMessage.indexOf("time") >= 0) {
    var date = new Date();
    var h = date.getHours();
    var m = date.getMinutes();
    send_message("Current time is: " + h + ":" + m);
  } else {
    $.post(path,
      {
        userMessage: newMessage
      },
      function(data) {
        //alert("inside ajax"+data);
        send_message(data);
      });

    /* $.get(path,function(data){
                    console.log("no match");
                    console.log(data);
                    send_message(data);
    }); */
  }
}

$(function() {
  $.ajax({
    url: "chatWindow.html",
    type: 'GET',
    success: function(data) {

      $('body').append(data);
      //$('#content').html($(data).find('#content').html());
      $('head').append('<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css" />');
      var logged_in = false;
      $(".pageTitleHeader").click(function() {
        logged_in = !logged_in;
        checkLogin();
      });

      function checkLogin() {
        if (logged_in)
          $(".contentBox").show();
        else
          $(".contentBox").hide();
      }

    }
  });

  get_userName();
  $("#textarea").keypress(function(event) {
    if (event.which == 13) {
      if ($("#enter").prop("checked")) {
        console.log("enter pressed");
        $("#send").click();
        event.preventDefault();
        //$("#textarea").val("");
      }
    }
  });
  $("#send").click(function() {

    var userName = "<span class='uname'>You: </span>";
    var latestMessage = $("#textarea").val();
    $("#textarea").val("");
    var prevState = $("#container").html();
    //console.log(prevState.length);
    if (prevState.length > 1) {
      prevState = prevState + "<br>";
    }
    $("#container").html(prevState + userName + latestMessage);
    $("#container").scrollTop($("#container").prop("scrollHeight"));
    ai(latestMessage);
  });
});

setTimeout(function() {
  $("#live-chat").css({
    "display": "block"
  });
}, 900); // 30 seconds in MS

// Store our panel into a variable.

var $myPanel = $("#live-chat");
// Get the height of the panel dynamically.
var $myPanelHeight = parseInt($myPanel.height());
// Immediately set the opacity to 0 - to hide it and set its bottom to minus its height.
$myPanel.css({
  "opacity": 0,
  "bottom": "-" + $myPanelHeight + "px"
});
// Set a timeout for the panel to slide and fade in.
setTimeout(function() {
  $myPanel.animate({
    // The CSS properties we want to animate (opacity and bottom position).
    opacity: 1,
    bottom: '0'
  }, 2000, function() {
    // Animation complete.
    // You can put other code here to do something after it has slid-in.
  });
}, 30000); // 30 seconds in MS

function getScripts(scripts, callback) {
  var progress = 0;
  scripts.forEach(function(script) {
    $.getScript(script, function() {
      if (++progress == scripts.length) callback();
    });
  });
}
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  background-color: #f2f2f2;
  font-family: arial, sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
}

#header {
  width: 100%;
  height: 60px;
  background-color: #333;
  box-shadow: 0px 4px 2px #333;
}

#header>h1 {
  width: 1024px;
  margin: 0px auto;
  color: white;
}

#container {
  width: 1024px;
  height: 400px;
  margin: 0px auto;
  margin-top: 20px;
  background-color: white;
  border: 1px solid #333;
  overFlow: scroll;
}

#controls {
  width: 1024px;
  margin: 0px auto;
}

#textarea {
  resize: none;
  width: 940px;
}

#send {
  font-size: 24px;
  position: absolute;
}

.uname {
  color: blue;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.chatBot {
  color: green;
  font-weight: bold;
}

#live-chat {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  /*   width: 200px;
    
        height: 100px;*/
  z-index: 5;
  background: #789;
  border-radius: 5px 5px 0 0;
  padding: 10px;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>
<body>
  <a href="page1.html">Page1</a>
  <a href="page2.html">Page2</a>
  <a href="page3.html">Page3</a>
  <div id="live-chat">
    <table width="100%" height="100%" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
      <tr class="livepageTitle">
        <td width="50%" class="maincurve" scope="col">
          <h1 class="pageTitleHeader">Live Chat</h1>
        </td>
        <td width="50%" class="maincurvecls" scope="col">
          <table border="0" align="right" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" id="tblPageContent">
            <tr>
              <!-- BODY STARTS -->
              <td height="31" align="right" valign="middle" nowrap class="innerPageTopLeftBGWithText">
                <dt:timeZone id="IST">IST</dt:timeZone>
                <dt:format pattern="dd-MMM-yyyy [hh:mm a z]" timeZone="IST">
                  <dt:currentTime />
                </dt:format>
                &nbsp;&nbsp;</td>

              <!--                                                                        <td width="14" height="31" align="right" valign="middle"><a href="#" title="Help" onClick="helpWindow('corporate/admin/admin_ma_accrts_add.htm')"><img src="/sbijava/images/help_icon.jpg" alt="Help" width="14" height="13" border="0" align="middle"></a></td> -->

              <!--                                                                        <td width="29" height="31" align="right" valign="middle" class="helpAndPrintLinks" onClick="helpWindow('corporate/admin/admin_ma_accrts_add.htm')"><a href="#" title="Help">Help</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;</td> -->
            </tr>
            <!-- BODY ENDS -->
            <!-- FOOTER STARTS -->
            <!-- FOOTER ENDS -->
          </table>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <!-- Tab starts -->
      <tr class="contentBox">
        <td colspan="2" align="left" valign="top" scope="row" class="pageContentBG">
          <table width="98%" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="tabtblbrdr">
            <!-- <tr>
                 <td colspan="6" class="innerPageSectionHeading">Select the Date Range </td>
        </tr> -->
            <tr>
              <td align="left" width="30%">
                <!--         <div id="header">
                       <h1>jQuery Chatbot v. 1.0</h1>
                       </div> -->
                <div id="container"> </div>
                <div id="controls">
                  <textarea id="textarea" placeholder="Enter your message here..."></textarea>
                  <button id="send">Send</button>
                  <br>
                  <input checked type="checkbox" id="enter">
                  <label>Send on enter</label>
                </div>
              </td>
            </tr>
          </table>
          <br>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Ok, so there's a LOT wrong with this - I'm looking to fix it for you, bare with me :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, let me first start by telling you why this wasn't working. There are quite a few reasons.

The specific styles that were making this break are below.

```
 #controls {
   width: 1024px; /* This width */
   margin: 0px auto;
 }

 #textarea {
    resize: none;
    width: 940px; /* This width */
 }
 #container {
    width: 1024px; /* This width */
    height: 400px;
    margin: 0px auto;
    margin-top: 20px;
    background-color: white;
    border: 1px solid #333;
    overFlow: scroll;
}
```

You can see here that across numerous classes you are using, the width is quite large. You have also used tables and I'm not quite sure why.  They aren't needed, especially for what you're working on.  I've stripped all of these out as for what you need, you can achive with purely css.

There's more I would change with this, but this answer is to specifically address your question around alignment. You can find my changes below.  If you have any questions about what I have done, I'm happy to explain.

```css
    #live-chat {
        position: absolute;
        bottom: 0px;
        right: 20px;
        width: 300px;
        height: auto;
        z-index: 5;
        background: #789;
        border-radius: 5px 5px 0 0;
        padding: 10px;
        display: block;
        box-sizing: border-box;
    }
        #send {
        font-size: 24px;
        margin-top: 10px;
    }
        #textarea {
        resize: none;
        width: 100%;
    }
```

```html
        <a href="page1.html">Page1</a>
        <a href="page2.html">Page2</a>
        <a href="page3.html">Page3</a>

        <div id="live-chat">
            <h1 class="pageTitleHeader">Live Chat</h1>
            <!-- 
            <dt:timeZone id="IST">IST</dt:timeZone>
            <dt:format pattern="dd-MMM-yyyy [hh:mm a z]" timeZone="IST">
                <dt:currentTime />
            </dt:format> -->

            <a href="#" title="Help" onClick="helpWindow('corporate/admin/admin_ma_accrts_add.htm')"><img src="/sbijava/images/help_icon.jpg" alt="Help" width="14" height="13" border="0" align="middle"></a>

            <textarea id="textarea" placeholder="Enter your message here..."></textarea>
            <button id="send">Send</button>

            <input checked type="checkbox" id="enter">

        </div>
```

Comment: Please send by jsfiddle

Comment: can you add up and down arrow when open and closing?

Comment: Hi, you should try that yourself, it's good to learn.  If I have answered your question, please mark the question as answered :)